# Tumblr Current Post Index number within Loop

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm trying something pretty simple but I can't figure it out!
I'm trying to access the current index of the post in the block:posts loop in tumblr.
Basically I need to display a div every 4 posts (so after the 4th posts, after the 8th post, ...)
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Render at specified offset

Tumblr provides a block, that allows you to render content based on a post offset, using: `{block:Post[1-15]} {/block:Post[1-15]}`.

Below is an example based on the OP's requirements:

```
{block:Posts}

<div class="post">
...
</div>

{block:Post4}
  <div>I am the 4th post.</div>
{/block:Post4}

{block:Post8}
  <div>I am the 8th post.</div>
{/block:Post8}

{block:Post12}
  <div>I am the 12th post.</div>
{/block:Post12}

{/block:Posts}
```

**Reference**

Post Blocks / Variables : http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts